Why does `BigInt(n)` return a different integer than `n`?
JavaScript's number can represent 18446744073709552000:
> n = '18446744073709552000'
> Number(n)
18446744073709552000
> String(Number(n)) === n
true

So I would expect BigInt(18446744073709552000) to return 18446744073709552000n but it actually returns 18446744073709551616n:
> BigInt(18446744073709552000)
18446744073709551616n

Why is that?

Why are you converting it to a Number instead of a BigInt? The question does not make sense.

@Pointy OP wants to demonstrate that using the number 18446744073709552000 has not lost precision, but actually represents the value 18446744073709552000, before passing it to BigInt. So I don't think this is a duplicate.

@Bergi I don't think it's a dup either, the dup linked does not seem to have anything to do with this question

@Bergi however I still think the question is anything but clear, there is no BigInt math in the posted code.

@Pointy I've put it from the text into a second code snippet. Clearer now?

@Pointy I think I found an actually suitable duplicate target. It even concerns the exact same integer!

The exact reason, I don't know it. However, I guess it's just a loss of precision from how it converts the number to its internal BigInt representation. You can prove it by doing any operation over the number: It will have wrong results

"JavaScript's number can represent 18446744073709552000 [...]": This premise is incorrect. Binary 111... (64 digits) is equal to decimal 18446744073709551616.

@Iván On the contrary, the conversion to bigint keeps the precise integer value. It's the String(…) conversion that has limited precision (as appropriate)

The question is why there either Number.toString doesn't lose the precision or why there are rounding issues when using BigInt

Tried this with Java, and regardless of the rounding I'm getting 18446744073709551616. So the question becomes why the interpreter manages to print 18446744073709552000. The interpreter probably inlines the value and forgets to round. Even adding 1 and subtracting it again still prints 18446744073709552000.

@MaartenBodewes See the duplicate for the answer. It has nothing to do with inlining or "forgetting to round". It's really just that the string '18446744073709552000' is a nice round decimal representation of the floating point value, which is just what toString should return. You do generally not want an exact representation of the floating point value beyond the number's precision. Maybe '18446744073709552e3' would have been better since it gives a hint at the limited precision, but neither is wrong.

@Bergi Yeah, but all said, I'm still not getting why it would round to this "nice number". I mean, I prefer the correct number as stored over 'nice round'. This is definitely not according to the principle of least surprise and it sucks when debugging edge cases.

OMG, it is the value you expect for 32 bit floats. Sheesh.

@MaartenBodewes no, it's a 64 bit double. And you do prefer nice round numbers for decimals, like String(0.1) should return "0.1" and not the exact number as stored ("0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625"). Yes, floating point math sucks, but everyone expects that.

@Bergi The thing is that I was wondering why that goes for things before the dot. And when I converted the 64 bit double to float in Java it turned back into 18446744073709552000. So I think that the method for printing the 64 bit float actually turns it into a 32 bit float first. Otherwise the rounding doesn't make any sense. But yeah, I could still be mistaken and the value is correctly rounded half-up after so many digits.

@MaartenBodewes No 32 bit conversion involved. It's just that toString prints only enough significant decimal digits to distinguish the number from adjacent Number values, then fills up the rest with 0. This happens for up to 21 digits, only above that it switches to exponential notation.

Thanks everyone. both duplicates help to explain the issue, which was that I wasn't losing precision if i could round trip a string to number and back and get the same string. I'm the future how where I get the precise value of a number?

s/where/would. How would I check that 18446744073709552000 or 0.1 aren't precisely represented in f64, and check what value they are exactly converted to?

For large integers, you can use BigInt(…) to get the precise mathematical value of the floating point number. For decimals, it's a bit more complicated. Probably best to throw into some interactive floating point display tool, like https://evanw.github.io/float-toy/ or https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

https://float.exposed/ is great for understanding cases like this.
